# Can't open an app as root. Sudo command not found

Tags: catalina, sudo

I'm trying to install the torrent downloader Vuze and every time I try to open the Vuze Installer via the terminal, in my case,

```
sudo /Users/naza/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.app
```

after put the password the therminal says

```
sudo: /Users/naza/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.app: command not found
```

I'm a new MacOS user but I know I can install the app by [just going root](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) and log in as root user in another session but I read that is recommended to do it with sudo via the terminal.

I just installed MacOS Catalina, it would be weird if something, as the sudo command, is missing.

I also tried to use the SU command

```
su /Users/naza/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.app
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The terminal answers `su: Sorry`. I read that's because the command isn't on for non-root users, same if I try `sudo su  /Users/naza/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.app`, the terminal respond `su: unknown login: su`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the installer as root. I took a quick look at the instructions on the Vuze website's download page, and it just says to double-click the installer normally. root is normally disabled for login on macOS, and it's really rare to see a graphical app (which a .app is) that's supposed to run as root.

Comment: The installer, once open, says "you must be logged in as root when installing this program"

Comment: I just tried installing `VuzeInstaller` (it is a java program I think not a normal app) and it only gave the "*You must be logged in as root*" message after I **cancel** the request to enter administrator name/password from *install4j* program. Did you see this prompt?

Comment: It just gives me the you must be logged in as root message, it's weird.
So, there's no way to open an executable as root via the terminal?

Comment: Same problem here:  "you must be logged in as root when installing this program", and using sudo with the terminal.

Comment: @Hikarus Are you running the Installer (without sudo) from a user account with admin rights?

Comment: The "command not found" is the path to the app, not the actual sudo command. `sudo` inteprets your path as a bash command which it is not. Try `sudo open -a "/Users/naza/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.app"`, or better just run the executable as the answer below says.

Answer (score 7):

You need to execute the unix executable, normally found in `some.app/Contents/MacOS`. To browse the app contents, right click on the app, and choose "Show package Contents".

You can simply drag and drop the executable in a Terminal window to get its path. Or you can right click, hold alt and choose "Copy as pathname".

Run the command below first, using `sudo` on any executable is not recommended.

```
/Volumes/Vuze\ Installer/Vuze\ Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

This of course assumes that you have already mounted the .dmg file downloaded from Vuze website.

Comment: Why not copy the installer app from DMG to ~/Downloads or /Applications ?

Answer (score 1):

I could only solve this by enabling the root user via MacOS' DIRECTORY UTILITY (which you can find via spotlight or /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app). Within the app, click on the usual lock to make changes, then go to the Edit Menu ⟶ Enable Root User. You will be prompted to create a password for the root user, which can be the same from your admin user. You can then log out your user, log in with root, install vuze, log in again with your usual user, and Vuze is ready to run. Ta-da! :)